# When does the null-cone consist entirely of eigenvectors?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, reductive-groups, nilpotent-cone

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional representation of a complex reductive Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$.

For our purposes, we may define the null-cone like this: $v\in V$ belongs to the null-cone if and only if there is a semisimple $h\in\mathfrak g$ and a decomposition $v=v_1+...+v_k$ such that $hv_1=\lambda_1v_1$, ..., $hv_k=\lambda_kv_k$ for some strictly positive $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$.

By the Jacobson-Morozov theorem, for the adjoint representation one does not need the decomposition: $v$ is nilpotent if and only if it is the eigenvector with nonzero eigenvalue for some semisimple element. By Vinberg's  theory of theta-groups this is true more generally for the action of $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak a^{(0)}$ on $V=\mathfrak a^{(1)}$ for a cyclically graded Lie algebra $\mathfrak a=\bigoplus_{j\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z}\mathfrak a^{(j)}$.

There are however very easy examples showing that in general the decomposition is necessary.
For example, the form $f=x^5+x^3y^2$ is in the null-cone of the 6-dimensional irrep of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ but $gf=\lambda f$ implies $g=0$ for any $g\in\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

I do know one example of a representation which does not come from a theta-group but still has the property that a vector is in the nullcone if and only if it is the eigenvector with nonzero eigenvalue for a semisimple element. This representation is however so ugly and obscure that I do not want to reproduce it here.

Is there known the characterization of some natural nice class of representations, not contained in the one coming from theta-groups, which has the same property? That is, such that any element of the null-cone is the eigenvector for a semisimple element with nonzero eigenvalue?